# My WordPress website has suffered fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WP_Site_Health::get_instance()

Tags: wordpress

My WordPress website has suffered a fatal error details below:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WP_Site_Health::get_instance() in /home/alfmanso/public_html/wp-settings.php:524 Stack trace: #0 /home/alfmanso/public_html/wp-config.php(89): require_once() #1 /home/alfmanso/public_html/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/alfmanso/...') #2 /home/alfmanso/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/alfmanso/...') #3 /home/alfmanso/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/alfmanso/...') #4 {main} thrown in /home/alfmanso/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 524
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did something change on your site? Did you install any new plugins or update themes? WP_Site_Health is a core Class. If you didn't make any changes, you might have to reinstall WordPress core.

Comment: Ok it worked. But instead of installing new WordPress version. I downloaded updated WordPress version and transferred wp includes and wp admin to my public html in cpanel and the website worked

Comment: Yeah, you essentially reinstalled the WP core doing that. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You must manually update WordPress.

Backup your database.

Backup *all* your WordPress files in your WordPress directory. Don’t forget your `.htaccess` file.

Verify the backups you created are there and usable. This is essential.

Deactivate *all* your Plugins.

Ensure first four steps are completed. Do not attempt the upgrade unless you have completed the first four steps.

Download and extract the WordPress package from the [official WordPress site](https://wordpress.org/download/).

Delete the old WordPress files on your site, but *do not delete*:

- `wp-config.php` file;
- `wp-content` folder; Special Exception: the `wp-content/cache` and the `wp-content/plugins/widgets` folders should be deleted.
- `wp-images` folder;
- `.htaccess` file–if you have added custom rules to your `.htaccess`, do not delete it;
  – `robots.txt` file–if your blog lives in the root of your site (ie. the blog is the site) and you have created such a file, do not delete it.

Upload the new files from your computer  to the appropriate WordPress folder on your site.

Run the WordPress upgrade program and follow the instructions on the screen. Then do this:

- Update Permalinks and `.htaccess`.
- Install updated Plugins and Themes.
- Reactivate Plugins
- Review what has changed in WordPress.

For more information, consult this page on [WordPress’ official support site here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/upgrading-wordpress-extended-instructions/).